# How can Azure App Service (web app) access other VM via private IP?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure app service (web app) and a VM contain some infrastructure (database, queue...)
Can App Service access VM via internal IP ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate your app to the Vnet which your VM in. Follow the steps in this document [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) and then you can access the VM with your private IP.

Comment: Under my app service/networking, not have any option to choose a VNet, just have options for CDN and retrict IP

Comment: It seems just supports for Windows type web app currently.

Comment: Is this Windows or Linux WebApp? Upgrade your App Service plan (Windows) and then check.

Comment: that is Linux web app, then it not support that feature?

Comment: It seems like that. Maybe you need to use an ASE for your web app. But it should be created before your web app.